# How to generate Stencil+Ionic4 PWA components with CLI

Tags: ionic4, stenciljs

I'm using Stencil with Ionic4 to create a PWA. I've generated my project with this command:

```
npx create-stencil ionic-pwa
```

How can I generate a new component using the CLI? Which CLI do I have to use? Stencil or Ionic CLI? Could you please give me an example (e.g. `generate component my-new-component`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found this third-party tool, which works well.

https://github.com/AkashGutha/generator-stencil

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-stencil
yo stencil:component
```